# Is there a way to swap between logical operators on the basis of some boolean?

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I'm implementing a bracket function for practice. The function will pinpoint a range between which either the minimum or maximum of some function takes place.

To give this option of either identifying a minimum or maximum, I allow the user to pass in a boolean, findMin.

The following code block identifies a minimum; the only difference between this block and one that would identify a maximum is that the comparison operators ("<" and ">") must be swapped with each other. I could easily make that swap by inserting an identical code block (but for swapped comparison operators) handled by an if statement entered only if the user wanted to find a maximum. Without having to add another such code block, is there a way to swap the comparison operators "<" and ">"?

```
def bracket (func, x, findMin, stepSize = 0.001):

    # Determine which direction is downward
    increment = 0.001
    if func(x+stepSize) > func(x):
        stepSize *= -1
        increment *= -1

    pointer = x + stepSize
    previousPointer = x
    while(func(pointer) < func(previousPointer)):
        previousPointer = pointer
        pointer += stepSize
        stepSize += increment

    a = min(pointer, previousPointer)
    b = max(pointer, previousPointer)

    return a,b
```

Comment: you could use the same the method for finding the minimum, and to find the maximum that is equivalent to find the minimum of the negative of the function in the same interval, so you could make `if not findMin: func = lambda x: -func(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can express a comparison operator as a function using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

E.g. the expression `1 > 2` is equivalent to calling `operator.gt(1, 2)`.

This is a way to pass it to a function:

```
import operator

def test(arg1, arg2, compare_function):

    if compare_function(arg1, arg2):
        print("condition is true")
    else:
        print("condition is false")
```

Output:

```
>>> test(1, 2, operator.lt)
condition is true
>>> test(1, 2, operator.gt)
condition is false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes:

```
Operator    Method
 ==        __eq__()
 !=        __ne__()
 >         __gt__()
 >=        __ge__()
 <         __lt__()
 <=        __le__()
```

For example:

```
class foo(object):
    """It's fun to override """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def __gt__(self, other):
        # Write your logic  here ...
        return self.name < other.name
```

And Now you can compare them:

```
In [2]: g = foo(6)
In [3]: y = foo(4)

In [4]: g>y
Out[4]: False

In [5]: g<y
Out[5]: True
```